# 'data:,' in the address bar while using chromedriver 112.0.5615.49

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Is chrome driver 112.0.5615.49 compatible with selenium 3.141.0?
I just update google chrome: 112.0.5615.138
and chrome driver 112.0.5615.49
with selenium 3.141.0
All of sudden getting below error in non-headless mode. When I running in headless=true it is working just fine. Any idea why?

HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

reinstall google chrome and and driver.